# How well does signalr support cellular?

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I am building a native iOS app that uses signalr for a chat feature.  I've experienced a lot of disconnecting and reconnecting of signalr while using it on my device.  These connection issues are rare while on wifi but much more common when using 3G to connect to the internet.  I am using a third-party signalr library to make the connections: [DyKnow/Signalr-Objc](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC).  I am not sure if the issue is because of the third-party library, the limitations of signalr and web sockets, or some mixture of the two.

How well does signalr work on a cellular connection?

Comment: I am having the same issue with SignalR on 3G internet, Update me if you now have some solution.

Comment: Having issues with SignalR on 3G even on Android as well.

Comment: I have tested using wifi and 3G and noticed that sometimes it takes time to connect server hub.Also while using 3G even connected to server it not deliver messages.Turning on wifi delivers the message.I have tried a lot to make client server stable connection but not able to found fruitful solution.